# Tests with different data models

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, model, nunit

Many of my class level unit tests load a data model and perform various class level tests. However, much of the business logic depends on the data in the model. Therefore my class level testing looks like this:

```
 public class TestFoo
 {
     // Data model
     Model _myDataModel; 

     // Class under test
     Foo _foo;

     [Setup] 
     public void Initialize()
     {
         // Create data model
         _myDataModel = new Model();
         _myDataModel.Load();   // Loads the file

         // Create the class under test
         _foo = new Foo();
     }

     [TearDown]
     public void Dispose()
     {
     }

     [Test]
     public void TestFooCase1()
     {
         // Code for test case that tests _foo and uses the data model  
     }
 }
```

However, I would like to run the bulk of my tests with two or more data models, i.e. I need to call`_myDataModel.LoadModelX()` or `_myDataModel.LoadModelY()` in the setup method.

One way I thought of doing this is by instantiating the model in the test case itself as shown below but this requires having to call the load method in every test case.

```
[Setup] 
public void Initialize()
{       
    // Create the class under test
    _foo = new Foo();
}

[TearDown]
public void Dispose()
{
}

// Use TestCase to specify the model as an argument for each test case  
[TestCase(modelX)]
[TestCase(modelY)]
public void TestFooCase1(string modelName)
{
    // Create data model
    _myDataModel = new Model();
    _myDataModel.Load(modelName);   // New method which loads the specific model 

    // Code for test case that tests _foo and uses the data model       
}
```

I'm thinking there must be a better approach possibly by defining my own attribute or extending the NUnitTestFixture.  I'm interested in other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a property for each combination of models you wish to test, then use the [ValueSource attribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=valueSource&r=2.5) to pass in the ready-loaded Model. Something like this

```
private static IEnumerable<Model> ModelsToTest
{
  get
  {
    Model x = new Model();
    x.Load("X");
    yield return x;

    Model y = new Model();
    y.Load("Y");
    yield return y;
  }
}

[Test]
public void TestFooCase1([ValueSource("ModelsToTest")] Model model)
{
  // Code for test case that tests _foo and uses the data model       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> much of the business logic depends on the data in the model

Considering that I would suggest creating separate tests for the each model specific case and do not mix different modelx into single tests fixture.

BTW, rename `Dispose()` method to `TearDown()`, because Dispose intuitively associated with Dispose pattern implementation (`IDisposable`) so this messed up things because you only doing regular NUnit ЕearDown stage which clearly identified by attribute [TearDown].

Answer (score 0):

I don't like setups and teardowns, because I want the information present in the test method. Thus, I prefer to create all testdata in the test, and I find it ESSENTIAL that the object under test is created in the test method.

What I do like is the builder pattern for creation of testdata.

```
public class DataModelBuilder
{  
  string _modelName; 
  IDataModel _dataModel; 

  public DataModelBuilder WithModelName(string modelName)
  {
    _modelName = modelName; 
    return this; 
  }

  public IDataModel Build()
  {
    _dataModel = new DataModel(); 
    _datamodel.Load(_modelName); 
    return _dataModel; 
  }

}
```

In the test method, the syntax for creating the model will be:

```
IDataModel _model = new DataModelBuilder().WithNewName("modelY").Build();
```

Nice and crisp one-line-creation of complex testdata with the benefit of showing all information relevant to the test case IN the test case. I don't want that information tucked away in a setup method.

Note, that builders become even more powerful in combination with mocking.

Answer (score -1):

I don't like `[Setup]`, `[TearDown]` attributes thus declared next class:

```
class DisposableList : List<IDisposable>, IDisposable
{
    public Dipose()
    {
        foreach (var x in this) x.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
[Test...]
public void MyTest()
{
    using (NewContext(...))
    {
        // perform test here
    }
}

private static NewContext(...)
{
    var list = new DisposableList();

    // add anything here

    return list;
}
```

Benefits:

- You can initialize test state (call `NewContext()`) several times in a single test or class
- You can initialize test state with different values, e.g. `NewContext((x) => x.LoadY())`

Comment: Don't think this approach pretty helpful considering points you're highlighted, single test should be aware and test a single test case so why you need to initialize context multiple times in scope of a single test? But it could be interesting for the integration tests

Comment: @sil: Agree with 'test per case` approach, lead it, but refactoring of old, not leading such approach, tests is much more easy with this helper class.

Comment: @sil: But regarding attributes usage approach - you can initialize test class only once, and this helper class allows to do it in each test method, or even more often. That's I want to mention.

Comment: @abatishchev - No need to get hostile or make threats. Use that energy to improve your answer so I can remove the -1 ;)